# VB.Net - Some menustrip questions

Tags: vb.net, winforms, menustrip

So my MenuStrip property Dock is: None

1. My menustrip is not visible when I align it with tabcontrol but my linklabel is visible, how can I make my menustrip visible aswell?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjjJq.png

2. I want to change how the submenu will show when I click my Menu, by default it is showing at the right side

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJGvm.png

I want to make it show below the menu like this (edited)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lS2Pw.png

Comment: For Q1: Make sure that the `MenuStrip` is assigned as a child of the parent container you want to put it in.

Comment: Same problem here. how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

For your Third Query : Change `Alignment` of Your Parent Menu (e.g. Settings in your image ) to `Right`.

Answer (score 0):

This would probably be easier if you just used a button to show a ContextMenuStrip:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  ContextMenuStrip1.Show(Button1, _
         New Point(Button1.Width - ContextMenuStrip1.Items(0).Width, _
                   Button1.Height))
End Sub
```

Result:

[image]